# Strange "Compare To Constant" behavior

Tags: matlab, simulink

The behavior of Simulink block `Compare To Constant` boggles my mind !

[image: figure 1: this simple Simulink model]

It doesn't work for the particular value `268.03` but works for other values such as `15.68` as shown below. And I really don't understand why is this the case.

[image: figure 2]

For now, I'm able to do what I want by using strings instead as shown below:

[image: figure 3]

I still want to understand why the simple `Compare To Constant` block doesn't work for this particular value (maybe others too that I'm not aware of...).

Comment: What's your model step size? If it's not fixed then you might never hit that time exactly. And even if it is fixed you might be hitting floating point comparison issues, you should avoid comparing floating point numbers with `x==y`, and do something like `abs(x-y)<z` where `z` is very small (maybe the min step-size of your model in this case). See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab, and feed back if your model works when you've changed to the `abs` compare approach. The `display` block may also be rounding.

Comment: @Wolfie, my step size is a fixed 0.01 s. I see your point regarding floating point comparison and after checking it turned out to be the issue here. Indeed, the model works fine now that I changed the comparison to use a tolerance z. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Wolfie's comment I was able to make the model work.
[image]

where the code inside the Matlab Function block is as follows:

```
function y = fcn(u)
t = 0.01;

if abs(u - 268.03) < t
    y = 1;
else
    y = 0;
end
```

Comment: There are `abs`,  `subtract` and `compare to constant` blocks in Simulink, you'd be better using native blocks than going into a custom function block for things where native blocks exist

Comment: @Wolfie, Noted! Is there a reason for that?

Comment: It's easier to read without opening up the function blocks (Simulink is inherently a graphical programming language), it means you don't have lots of associated function files for things which can be achieved otherwise, and I assume it compiles more efficiently when running Simulink in [rapid] accelerator mode (or in code generation) although I don't have any reference for that.